# Change scroll button Icon on Material UI Tabs component

Tags: reactjs, scroll, tabs, navigation, material-ui

I need to change the icon of the scroll buttons (left and right) of Tabs component.

There's a props called 'ScrollButtonComponent, but I don't know how can I put different left and right icons in the buttons.

[Print of the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgEwI.png)

https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to TabScrollButton.js inside nodeModule folder
and then change KeyboardArrowLeft or KeyboardArrowRight inside ButtonBase section. [TabScrollButton](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Tabs/TabScrollButton.js)

```js
<ButtonBase
      component="div"
      className={className}
      ref={ref}
      role={null}
      tabIndex={null}
      {...other}
    >
      {direction === 'left' ? (
        <KeyboardArrowLeft fontSize="small" />
      ) : (
        <KeyboardArrowRight fontSize="small" />
      )}
    </ButtonBase>
  );
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't change code in node modules
Of course it is advisable never to touch the code in your node modules folder,
for one thing all your changes will be overwritten when you run npm install/update (or yarn) and no-one else will be able to replicate when they use your repo as you don't check node modules into git.

Here's is the exact solution:

Documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/

There is not much details is available on material-ui documentation. Here what you can do is there is a one property named ScrollButtonComponent. From where you can change the left/right icon.

```
 <Tabs
    value={value}
    classes={{ indicator: classes.tabsIndicator }}
    onChange={handleChange}
    indicatorColor="primary"
    textColor="primary"
    ScrollButtonComponent={(props) => {
        if (
            props.direction === "left" &&
            props.visible
        ) {
            return (
                <IconButton {...props}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        style={{
                            marginLeft: "7px"
                        }}
                        color="#007474"
                        icon="arrow-left"
                    />
                </IconButton>
            );
        } else if (
            props.direction === "right" &&
            props.visible
        ) {
            return (
                <IconButton {...props}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        style={{
                            marginLeft: "7px"
                        }}
                        color="#007474"
                        icon="arrow-right"
                    />
                </IconButton>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }}
    variant="scrollable"
    scrollButtons="on"
    aria-label="full width tabs example"
  >
    <Tab label="Item One" icon={<PhoneIcon />} {...a11yProps(0)} />
    <Tab label="Item Two" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} {...a11yProps(1)} />
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

[I used this answer and it work perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66706660/15028948)

However, instead of using `props.visible` I checked if disabled was false to display the appropriate icon. The props object didn't have the `visible` key

```
<Tabs
    value={value}
    classes={{ indicator: classes.tabsIndicator }}
    onChange={handleChange}
    indicatorColor="primary"
    textColor="primary"
    ScrollButtonComponent={(props) => {
        if (
            props.direction === "left" &&
            !props.disabled
        ) {
            return (
                <IconButton {...props}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        style={{
                            marginLeft: "7px"
                        }}
                        color="#007474"
                        icon="arrow-left"
                    />
                </IconButton>
            );
        } else if (
            props.direction === "right" &&
            !props.disabled
        ) {
            return (
                <IconButton {...props}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        style={{
                            marginLeft: "7px"
                        }}
                        color="#007474"
                        icon="arrow-right"
                    />
                </IconButton>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }}
    variant="scrollable"
    scrollButtons="on"
    aria-label="full width tabs example"
  >
    <Tab label="Item One" icon={<PhoneIcon />} {...a11yProps(0)} />
    <Tab label="Item Two" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} {...a11yProps(1)} />
</Tabs>
```